# Deploying CSS to SharePoint with PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-2010, powershell-2.0, wsp

I am currently trying automate Deploying of Branding changes to out Business Intelligence SharePoint site through PowerShell. I am using the following code to Deploy a WSP to my local instance of SharePoint for testing.

```
function Uninstall-AllSPSolutions {
param (
    [switch] $Local,
    [switch] $Confirm
) 

Start-SPAssignment -Global;
foreach($solution in (Get-SPSolution | Where-Object { $_.Deployed })) {
    write-host "Uninstalling Solution " $solution.Name;
    if($solution.DeployedWebApplications.Count -gt 0) {
       Uninstall-SPSolution $solution -AllWebApplications -Local:$Local -Confirm:$Confirm;
    } else {
       Uninstall-SPSolution $solution -Local:$Local -Confirm:$Confirm;
    }
   do {
       Start-Sleep 5;
       $solution = Get-SPSolution $solution;
      } while($solution.JobExists -and $solution.Deployed) 
} 
Stop-SPAssignment -Global;
}

function Remove-AllSPSolutions {
param (
    [switch] $Confirm
) 
Get-SPSolution | Where-Object { !$_.Deployed } | Remove-SPSolution -Confirm:$Confirm
}

echo "Loading Sharepoint Snapin" 
$snapin = Get-PSSnapin | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell" }
if ($snapin -eq $null) {
   Write-Host "[INIT] Loading SharePoint Powershell Snapin"
   Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell"
}

#Some variables
#Include Url Site
$SITEURL="sharepoint url"
#Include WSP File Path
$WSPFILEPATH="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\folder\SharepointDeployer.wsp"
#Include WSP Name
$WSPNAME="SharepointDeployer.wsp" 

echo "Uninstall Solutions"
Uninstall-AllSPSolutions -Confirm
echo "Remove Solutions"
Remove-AllSPSolutions -Confirm

echo Deploy Test solution
echo "1. Add Solution" 
Add-SPSolution $WSPFILEPATH
echo "2. Deploy Solution" 
#Install-SPSolution -identity $WSPNAME -force -AllWebApplications $SITEURL -GACDeployment
Install-SPSolution -identity $WSPNAME -force -AllWebApplications -GACDeployment
echo "2. Enable Feature" 
Enable-SPFeature –Identity "SharepointDeployer Feature1" –url  $SITEURL
```

The solution deploys just fine, as I can see it in in Central Admin, but the changes do not get made to the files when I look in SharePoint Designer.

All of the files have the following attributes to overwrite in the Module

```
IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="true" Type="GhostableInLibrary"
```

I have tried playing around with the Feature to see if it is an issue there, here are the results

Farm: I cannot generate the WSP through Visual Studio. The error is
The Project Item "Name of Module" cannot be deployed through a Feature with Farm Scope

Site: The Feature is not a Farm Level Feature and is not found in a Site Level defined by the Url

Web: Same as above

WebApplication: I get the same error as Farm except it says WebApplication Scope

I am not sure what I need to do to make this work, as it should be simple (we are talking 3 CSS files, 2 images, and a masterpage)

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there are two possible reasons for the resources to stay outdated

- you have custom changes. you are deploying files to the hive, but your virtual folder is not showing the site definitions. you can add on your script the code to revert resources to site definitions to make sure your changes apply
- you are not deactivating the features. if you retract a solution and redeploy it, the features will not be properly updated and sharepoint will likely think that they were activated all along. you should add the deactivate call before your retraction

good kuck